# Как заставить установиться Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Я скачал инсталлер Visual Studio Community Edition. И мне предложили начать установку, но для этого необходимо "кое-что настроить". Нажал продолжить, установилось около 60 мегабайт. После этого "Почти готово... Все готовиться" и спустя пол минуты окошко просто закрывается, ни ошибки, ничего. При повторной попытке то же самое, только уже не требовалось заново устанавливать 60 мегабайт.

Comment: откуда вы его скачали этот инсталлер?

Comment: С оффициальной страницы Microsoft

Comment: я посмею допустить что проблема у вас где-то, я скачал инсталлер с офф. сайта, там скачало около 60мб, дальше перешло на страничку выбора компонентов для установки, попробуйте удалить а потом снова установить инсталлер может поможет

Comment: Пробовал. А вы не можете подсказать куда качаются те 60мб (по какому пути)? Хочу попробовать отчистить и заново их скачать

Comment: я думаю что это плохая идея чистить 60мб, это вероятнее всего временные файлы, скиньте ссылку в вопрос откуда вы это все качаете

Comment: Отсюда https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/. При этом Visual Studio Code скачался без проблем

Comment: добавил ответ с рабочей ссылкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я качаю VisualStudio с [этого](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) сайта. После загрузки у меня идет такое окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я со всем соглашаюсь и идем дальше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после загрузки я перехожу в окошко выбора компонентов для загрузки и установки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то так должно все быть :) Попробуйте еще раз в соответствии с моими скриншотами и у вас все должно получится.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня заново начали качаться эти 60 мегабайт и после этого процесс пошел